# np.insert problem. I can not insert all string (python3.7; numpy1.19.2 )

Tags: python, numpy

I am a beginner of python. (I am not good at English)
I want to use pandas to execute some excel files.

```
import numpy as np

Res = [['CS管理','教師管理','1']]
Res = np.insert(Res, 0, values='Administrator', axis=1)
print(Res)
```

Expectation is

```
 [['Administrator' 'CS管理' '教師管理' '1']]
```

Output is

```
[['Admi' 'CS管理' '教師管理' '1']]
```

What should I do to deal with it?
Looking forward to your reply

[image]

Comment: Please provide a copy-paste of the entire exception stack trace.

Comment: Please provide the exact required output

Comment: In fact, no exception in cmd. What I want is the insert the values

Comment: I used Python 2.7 and I did not meet the problem

Comment: there is no such thing as python 2.7 anymore :)

Comment: Right, I feel confused about it (┬＿┬）

Comment: `Res[0].insert(0, 'Administrator')` gives you the expected result. `numpy.insert` does not add longer string than in the target object. I do not know why. It looks like `numpy` silently considers string as additional dimension, but I do not see any explanations. It works the same for me both for python 3.6 and python 2.7. Maybe this behavior changed with `numpy` version.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness! Your answer can help me to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Res` is an array with strings that are 4 characters long:

```
In [87]: Res = np.array([['CS管理','教師管理','1']])
In [88]: Res
Out[88]: array([['CS管理', '教師管理', '1']], dtype='<U4')
```

The result from `insert` still has the 'U4' dtype, so it truncates the insert.

```
In [89]: np.insert(Res, 0, values='Administrator', axis=1)
Out[89]: array([['Admi', 'CS管理', '教師管理', '1']], dtype='<U4')
```

If we start with a longer `dtype`:

```
In [99]: Res = np.array([['CS管理','教師管理','1']], 'U15')
In [100]: Res
Out[100]: array([['CS管理', '教師管理', '1']], dtype='<U15')
In [101]: np.insert(Res, 0, values='Administrator', axis=1)
Out[101]: array([['Administrator', 'CS管理', '教師管理', '1']], dtype='<U15')
```

An alternative is the variable length `object` dtype:

```
In [102]: Res = np.array([['CS管理','教師管理','1']], object)
In [103]: Res
Out[103]: array([['CS管理', '教師管理', '1']], dtype=object)
In [104]: np.insert(Res, 0, values='Administrator', axis=1)
Out[104]: array([['Administrator', 'CS管理', '教師管理', '1']], dtype=object)
```

Whether one is better than the other may depend on further processing you are doing.

Since you are adding the new string at the start, a concatenate would be just as good:

```
In [106]: Res = np.array([['CS管理','教師管理','1']])
In [108]: np.concatenate((np.array([['Administrator']]),Res), axis=1)
Out[108]: array([['Administrator', 'CS管理', '教師管理', '1']], dtype='<U13')
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations! It helped me.